# Storing command output into a Variable in Bash

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

NEW_TEXT="if failed Send to Karn Kumarl"

OLD_FILE="$(awk '{print $1}' RMANJOBS | while read JB;do autorep -j $JB -q;done | egrep "^/|^insert_job|^description" | sed '0~3 a\\')"

NEW_FILE="MRMANJOBS"

AWK='''
    #.. Get new text from the shell variable.
    BEGIN { NewText = " " ENVIRON["TXT"] "\042"; }
    #.. If this line needs the fix, substitute the text.
    /^description:.* [Ii]f failed / { sub (/ [Ii]f failed .*$/, NewText); }
    #.. Print all lines, whether fixed or not.
    { print; }
    '''

TXT="${NEW_TEXT}" awk "${AWK}" "${OLD_FILE}" > "${NEW_FILE}"
```

I need to sort the command output into a variable .. as its not taking for OLD_FILE.

Comment: Does it work if you just get rid of the outer quotes?  They aren't necessary and might be messing you up

Comment: @Eric - Even it doesn't work using without quotes like $().. While i am executing this script it simply display the command line output on the screen, while it should hold it and put it into NEW_FILE.

Comment: Well, my standard next advice for this would be to put `set -x` at least before the line that's giving you trouble so you can see what it looks like when the variables are all expanded, perhaps you'll spot the issue that way.

Comment: I kept the set -x but it doesn't shows any issues though, Just prints the output of OLD_FILE  on the screen.

Only error i can see is "for reading (File name too long)"   in the output.

Comment: Can you show what is in OLD_FILE variable? (the output of `awk '{print $1}' RMANJOBS | while read JB;do autorep -j $JB -q;done | egrep "^/|^insert_job|^description" | sed '0~3 a\\'` command). Why you put empty lines after each 3rd?

Comment: Change last line to `TXT="${NEW_TEXT}" awk "${AWK}" <<<"${OLD_FILE}" > "${NEW_FILE}"`

Comment: @Costas - In OLD_FILE variable, it contains the output of the command as you highlighted , Howerver , about placing empty line after each 3 lines motive to output separated after 3 lines which will be further used with another command (autosys JIL) and that command needs space after 3 lines to update the JOBS.

So, The output of the command OLD_FILE will be send to the NEW_FILE after changing the text and that NEW_FILE will be used to modify the JOBS thats actually a tools which needs the output in this form.
jil<NEW_FILE.

Comment: @Costas - It works , can you explain the change specially "<<<"${OLD_FILE}" >"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read JB last
do
    autorep -j $JB -q
done < RMANJOBS |
sed -rn "/^\/|^insert_job|^description/{
    s/(description:.* [Ii]f failed )[^"]*/\1Send to Karn Kumarl/
    s/insert/update/
    p
    }" |
sed '0~3 G' > MRMANJOBS
```

Comment: @Costas- Can you explain Please

Comment: This new script does not work .. it throws error for sed..

sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `|'

Comment: @karn Sorry I'd make `/` escaped. Test repaired.

Comment: `@Costas
1- Though the solution working fine but here we forgot to "awk '{print $1}' RMANJOBS" Part to print the $1 as this has many feilds.

2- We need the last word to be closed with double quotes as below.<br/>

description: "Unmount TCFTP filesystems on ABC - if failed Send to Karn Kumarl" <br/>

3- Can we replace the string altogether with sed in the below line which you suggested...<br/>

sed -rn "/^\/|^insert_job|^description/  <br/>

--> I need string "insert" to be replaced with "update"`

Comment: @karn 1/ You need not use `awk` due to `read JB last` which put in `JB` just 1st field. 2/ As I understand quotes there are in line already? 3/ I'm not sure to clear understand what you need.

Comment: I'll Provide the details. By the way what thast "last" mean, I am a newbie so,apologies fir asking so many things.

Comment: @karn `last` is a variable in which stores remaining part of the line(without  first field which stores in `JB` variable)